# how to click on interactive rectangle button on graphics.py and close window

Tags: python-3.x, graphics

Graphic.py python to click button rectangle.

** Problem **

need to capture mouse on graphics rectangle (simulated button) in python, and close window.

** Click How to reach rectangle **

For "quitButton" where and how to click on "quitButton" using only graphics.py library and no other libraries, just python and graphics.py

** Python graphic code **

```
from graphics import *


def clickRectangle():
    win = GraphWin("",600,270)      

    pt1 = Point(300,175)
    pt2 = Point(370,205)
    quitButton = Rectangle(pt1,pt2)
    quitButton.setFill('PapayaWhip')
    quitButton.setOutline('black')
    quitButtonC = quitButton.getCenter()
    label1 = Text(quitButtonC,"Quit")
    label1.setSize(11)
    quitButton.draw(win)
    label1.draw(win)      
    
    for i in range (500):
        try:
            if (p.getX()> m.getX()) and (p.getX()< n.getX()):
                if (p.getY()> m.getY()) and (p.getY()< n.getY()):
                    win.close()      
        except:
            continue
        
         
        
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```